# Can't enable usb on VirtualBox

Tags: usb, virtualbox

I have installed the latest VirtualBox Extension Pack, I have used this:

```
sudo adduser $USER vboxusers
```

but I can't still make it work.

[image]

Comment: I believe you need to log out or reboot your PC.

Answer (score 0):

Shut Down the Kali in the virtual box and go to the settings again. If OS is working in the virtual box, settings doesn't enable.